# Generate object files ".o" while compiling project in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, object-files

I'm trying to generate the ".o" output of my ".cpp" files of my project in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010.

I already found the answer that says that to compile without link you have to just press Ctrl+F7, however where is that object file created?

Comment: I believe that object files on some Microsoft systems are called `*.obj` not `*.o` as on Linux. But the last time I compiled on a Microsoft system was in the 1980-s ....

Comment: Basile's memory is pretty good; Microsoft's compilers still create `*.obj` files. Look in the `Debug` or `Release` directories in your project folder.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch More fundamentally, Windows' object files are COFF while Linux and friends are ELF. I don't think Microsoft's compilers can even output ELF.

Comment: Yes, and Microsoft linking model, is according to what I remember from reading Levine's book on loaders and linkers, a mistake. Linux linking model is IMHO simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio creates *.obj files, which are always created, if you link them or not. The default directories are "Debug" and/or "Release", but this depends on the project settings.